# Stored Procedure combining resultsets

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

When I run below mysql stored procedure, I get three different tables as output. Is there any way, I can combine these three tables and display output as in a single table with different columns and single row ?

```
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `retrieveApplicantStatus`(IN in_userId INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT applicants_id, approval FROM applicants WHERE users_id = in_userId;

    SELECT pass_fail.result AS test_result, pass_fail.license_approval FROM pass_fail WHERE user_id = in_userId;

    SELECT result AS trial_result FROM trial_result WHERE user_id = in_userId;
END
```

Required Output :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
applicants_id | approval | test_result | trial_result | license_approval |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
              |          |             |              |                  |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `UNION ALL` ? If fact, if you want one row set, then all three of current tow sets should logically have same structure

Comment: THANKS for the reply, let me see how it looks like !

Comment: Ok, [go ahead and see](https://www.google.com/search?q=mysql+union+all)

Comment: Is it like it will return a single column ?

Comment: @AlmaDo, I ran through the page, but it isn't what i want. What i want is, single row and multiple columns from that procedure. Is there a way ?

Comment: Fine, now you can see how bad question will cause "answers, which are not what you want". So, please, clarify it in your question - provide current result set and also what should be result set. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may help a lot

Comment: So, What is the conclusion then, is it "there is no way"?

Comment: Is User_ID unique in each table? If it isn't your problem isn't even simple with a single table, i.e. if `SELECT result AS trial_result FROM trial_result WHERE user_id = in_userId;` returns two rows, how are you going to turn this into a single row, let alone 2 other tables with multiple rows?

Comment: @GarethD, USER_ID in each table is unique !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `user_id` is constrainted to be unique in each table then you can use:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `retrieveApplicantStatus`(IN in_userId INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT  u.in_userId,
            a.applicants_id, 
            a.approval,
            pf.result AS test_result, 
            pf.license_approval,
            tr.result AS trial_result
    FROM    (SELECT in_userId) AS u
            LEFT JOIN applicants AS a
                ON a.users_id = u.in_userId
            LEFT JOIN pass_fail AS pf
                ON pf.user_id = u.in_userId
            LEFT JOIN trial_result AS tr
                ON tr.user_id = u.in_userId;
END
```

**HOWEVER** If it is not constrained to be unique this will give you a cartesian product, i.e. 2 rows in each table will give you 8 rows in total, 3 rows in each table will give you 27 results.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use following code:-

```
BEGIN
    SELECT applicants_id, approval 
    FROM applicants WHERE users_id = in_userId;
        UNIION ALL
    SELECT pass_fail.result AS test_result, pass_fail.license_approval 
    FROM pass_fail 
    WHERE user_id = in_userId;
        UNION ALL
    SELECT result AS trial_result 
    FROM trial_result 
    WHERE user_id = in_userId;
END
```

Comment: _Sigh_ Please, at least try your code. It won't even be executed because of different count of columns in row sets

Comment: But as far as i m concern, if we want to select multiple columns from multiple tables then we have to use `UNION ALL` clause, as i do.

Comment: Yes, and as far as I see, you have many errors in your code: different count of columns for UNION, using sql delimiter inside query, mixing aliases for column and table e t.c. This is not what should be the answer for SO. Answers should be tested and after that - posted with all needed explanations.

Comment: Well, i was just trying to tell the logic rathar than to tell the whole code just like spoon fidding, thats why i haven't test the code. But still i want an excuse if somthing went wrong.